# How to run windows start service using inno setup?

Tags: windows-services, installation, inno-setup

i want to run windows start service in the icon section through command prompt using inno setup.pls help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't run things through the `[Icons]` section.

If you want an icon to start a service, use something like:

```
[Icons]
Name: {group}\Start Wibble service; Filename: net.exe; Parameters: "start wibbleservice";
```

Update after the question was clarified, but left here for posterity:
<strike>If you want Inno to start the service, you either use the [SCM API](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Service_-_Functions_to_Start%2C_Stop%2C_Install%2C_Remove_a_Service) called from the `AfterInstall` entry of the service itself or a `[Run]` entry:</strike>

```
[Run]
Filename: net.exe; Parameters: "start wibbleservice"; Description: "Starting wibble service"
```

Comment: yes.i want an icon to start a windows service (by Net Start "service Name") in cmd

Comment: ...which is what my answer gave you. Please accept it as the answer, or ask for clarification if you need further help with it.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail because i dont have enough experiance in inno setup.i was not clear with ur answer.i want to execute start  windows service through command line in cmd.exe equivalent things to be done when i click the icon

Comment: You copy and paste the first example code section in my answer. That will create an icon in your program group, that when clicked, will start your service.

Comment: one more doubt i want to run this on admin.is there is any flag that is used to run it in admin in icon section?

Comment: Not without creating your own program that has the suitable manifest and calles net.exe.